# Laravel pagination with URL parameter

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel application. One of the pages can be reached via the following URL

> http://localhost:8000/items/gallery?item_type=glasses

As the amount of items to be shown can be quite substantial, I'm using pagination. I have the following code in my view:

```
@foreach($media as $media_item)
   <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('storage/'.$media_item->id .'/'. $media_item->file_name)  }}" ">
       </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
{{ $media->links() }}
```

and in the controller, I'm using:

```
$media = Media::paginate(5);
```

The pagination buttons are shown and work for the 1st one. Then when I click on the second (or third or fourth...) one, I get the following error message:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

I see the link is trying to reach:

> http://localhost:8000/beeritems/gallery?page=2

whereas I need:

> http://localhost:8000/beeritems/gallery?item_type=glasses&page=2

In Laravel, how can I change the links() method to include the part after the question mark?

Comment: can you show your controller whole method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `->appends()` methods

```
$media = Media::paginate(5);
$media->appends($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use laravel basic URLs instead of getting gallery images with URL get parameters.
something like this:

define Route like this

```
/items/gallery/{types}
```

then using it like

```
http://localhost:8000/items/gallery/glasses
```

in this case you don't get that error anymore

Comment: Good suggestion, accepted answer works for now. Your suggestion requires quite some rework but definitely the better option. Thanks.